# TypeError: Object(...) is not a function when creating a JS object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am getting a TypeError: Object(...) is not a function compiler issue and I am not sure why, below are the corresponding files - I am specifically getting an issue where

```
const mySubmission =  GetStudentSubmissionWithUrl();
```

is run. My function GetStudentSubmissionWithUrl() returns a JavaScript object and I want to assign this object to another JavaScript object.

```
function Details () {
  

  const mySubmission =  GetStudentSubmissionWithUrl();

/* TODO: do the filtering of a submission in the backend instead of right here - will cause a big performance hit */

   return (
 
   <React.Fragment>

    {mySubmission?.images && <ImageCarousel imageList={mySubmission.images}/>}


     <div className="card-body">
       <h1 className="title-event">{}</h1>
 
       {mySubmission?.subjectName && <h2 className="title-location"> {mySubmission.subjectName}</h2>}
          
       <br></br>
      
       <div className="row=title">

 
       {mySubmission?.location && <h3 className="submitter-location">  {mySubmission.location}</h3>}
 
       {mySubmission?.description && <p> {mySubmission.description}</p>}
 
      
       </div>
 
       <br></br>
 
     </div>
 
     {mySubmission?.sources && <Source sourceList={mySubmission.sources}/>}
 
     </React.Fragment>
 
     );
 }

export default Details;
```

Here is where my corresponding GetStudentSubmissionWithUrl() is defined:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { getAllVerified } from '../util';

//return a StudnetSubmission given the current ulr link that we are in
function GetStudentSubmissionWithUrl() {

    const [submissions, setSubmissions] = useState(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchData = async () => {
            const data = await getAllVerified(); //just get the one
            setSubmissions(data);
        };
        fetchData();
      }, []);

    let str =  JSON.stringify(window.location.pathname);
    let submissionId = str.split("/").pop();


    submissionId = submissionId.replace('"', '');

    let mySubmission;
    if (submissions != null) {
    var arrayLength = submissions.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
        let string_id = submissions[i].id;
        string_id = string_id.replace('"', '');
        if (submissionId === string_id) {

            mySubmission = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(submissions[i]));
        }
        
    }
    }
    return mySubmission;
}

export default GetStudentSubmissionWithUrl;
```

Any help would be much appreciated - thanks in advance!

Comment: `GetStudentSubmissionWithUrl` looks to be a React function component. Don't invoke React functions directly. Render them as JSX and React handles instantiating them and handling the component lifecycle. Can you update your question to include the full error message and any stacktrace?

Comment: And make sure you're importing `GetStudentSubmissionWithUrl` in your file with the `Details` component

Comment: How are you importing that function?

Comment: @MattU - I am importing the function doing this: import { getAllVerified } from '../util';

Comment: You can't use react hooks outside of a React functional component or a custom hook which starts with the `use` keyword.

Comment: @SinanYaman Ah, great catch!